# Sending messages to the user via django signals

Tags: django

Forgive me if this question makes little sense; I have had little sleep as of late.

I want to send a notification to the user whenever a signal fires via django's messages module, but I am at a loss as to how to pass the request object to the messages.success method.

I'm doing this because whenever a user gets a badge I need to tell him about it. For example, when a user completes her profile, does a set number of ratings, or makes a certain number of comments a badge is rewarded. Right now the only way for the user to tell that she has a new badge is to go to the badge page, but I want to gently inform the user of the event.

Using django notifications would work, but the system we've got in place would be too jarring (currently it loads a modal) and more expensive since it hits the database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably don't want to do this.  Please explain why you're trying something like this.  Just display the message in your template is the usual solution.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: "whenever a user gets a badge"?  What?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Django messages framework operates against HTTP requests rather than users (so it also works for anonymous users).  A signal would have no idea of which request to attach a message to, and chances are the user in question probably wouldn't even be logged in at the time.

It sounds like what you're trying to do would be better suited to something like django-notification, http://github.com/jtauber/django-notification/ .

Comment: Ugh ... upon reconsideration the django notification route seems less enticing. Minimizing queries to the db is a priority.

Comment: Haha, it only took me four years to realize that this meets all requirements specified in my question.

Comment: @IntrepidDude: How are you messaging it? email? is there a way to show the notification at the moment of getting the badge? (in his browser or app). by the way awesome comment, returning after 4 years...

Comment: @eugene I still ended up using the messages framework. The event that the user needed notifying about happened asynchronously (in a celery task). 

Couldn't show the notification at the moment of getting the badge (because of what Rolo said), but DID create a function that checks the cache to see if the user needs to be notified, and added that function to the main views of the site.  edit: Submitted response prematurely.

Comment: @IntrepidDude How do you use message framework? doesn't it need `request` object and you said you are generating it in a celery task...?

Comment: @eugene The celery task sets a flag indicating whether or not the specific user needs to be notified about the event, and a decorator on certain views checks for that flag (for authenticated users) and uses the message framework to notify the user. Since the decorator is wrapping a view it has access to the request object.

Comment: @InterpidDude aye, thanks, btw, I found this yesterday, might interest you. https://github.com/jonashagstedt/swampdragon This adds ability django app to notify user real time

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the messages framework directly in a signal because you don't have access to a request.

You could probably get around this by wrapping a view that the user is likely to go to frequently with something that checks for new badges and creates a message. Then although they wouldn't get the message on the very next page viewed after receiving the badge, they would get it on the first page viewed after the page that does the message creation.